# Snakemake Wildcards SyntaxError

Tags: wildcard, snakemake, rna-seq

I know this is a common error and I already checked other posts but it didn't resolved my issue. I would like to use the name of the database I use for `SortMeRNA` rule (`rRNAdb=config["rRNA_database"]`) the same way I use `version=config["genome_version"]`. But obviously, I can't.

```
SyntaxError:
Not all output, log and benchmark files of rule SortMeRNA contain the same wildcards. This is crucial though, in order to avoid that two or more jobs write to the same file

......

import glob
import os

configfile : "config.json"


#################### GLOBAL VARIABLES #######################

OUTDIR = os.path.abspath(config["outdir"])


# ID NGS
idNGS = config["idNGS"]

# Fichiers FASTQ
DIR_FASTQ = config["dir_fastq"]

## PARAMETERS TRIMMOMATIC
w = config["w"]
Q = config["Q"]
m = config["m"]

## Bowtie2 database
BWT2_DB = config["BWT2_DB"]

## Templates multiQC
DIR_TPL = config["DIR_TPL"]


#### VERSIONS genomes and database ####
version = config["genome_version"]
rRNAdb = config["rRNA_database"]


####################### FASTQ FILES #########################

def list_samples(DIR_FASTQ): # create list with all sample names from fastq directory
    SAMPLES=[]
    for file in glob.glob(DIR_FASTQ+"/*.fastq.gz"):
        base=os.path.basename(file)
        sample=(base.replace('.fastq.gz', ''))
        SAMPLES.append(sample)
    return(SAMPLES)

SAMPLES = list_samples(DIR_FASTQ)


########################## RULES ############################

rule all:
    input:
        OUTDIR+"/multiQC/multiQC-PL09_"+idNGS+".html",
        OUTDIR+"/multiQC/multiQC-PL21_"+idNGS+".html"


rule fastQC:
    input: 
        DIR_FASTQ+"/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    output: 
        "{OUTDIR}/FastQC/{sample}_fastqc.zip",
        "{OUTDIR}/FastQC/{sample}_fastqc.html"
    threads:
        16
    shell:
        """
        fastqc {input} -o {OUTDIR}/FastQC/
        """ 

rule trimmomatic:
    input:
        DIR_FASTQ+"/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        trim_out="{OUTDIR}/Trimmomatic/{sample}_SL-{w}-{Q}_Min-{m}.fastq.gz",
        trim1_out="{OUTDIR}/Trimmomatic/{sample}_SL-{w}-{Q}_Min-{m}.stdout",
        trim1_err="{OUTDIR}/Trimmomatic/{sample}_SL-{w}-{Q}_Min-{m}.stderr"
    threads:
        16
    shell:
        "trimmomatic SE -phred33 {input} {output.trim_out} SLIDINGWINDOW:{w}:{Q} MINLEN:{m} > {output.trim1_out} 2> {output.trim1_err}"


rule Bowtie2:
    input:
        fasta_trim="{OUTDIR}/Trimmomatic/{sample}_SL-"+str(w)+"-"+str(Q)+"_Min-"+str(m)+".fastq.gz"
    output:
        BWT2_ERR="{OUTDIR}/Bowtie2/{sample}_SL-{w}-{Q}_Min-{m}_bowtie2_{version}.stderr",
        BWT2_SAM=temp("{OUTDIR}/Bowtie2/{sample}_SL-{w}-{Q}_Min-{m}_bowtie2_{version}.sam"),
        BWT2_BAM=temp("{OUTDIR}/Bowtie2/{sample}_SL-{w}-{Q}_Min-{m}_bowtie2_{version}.bam"),
        BWT2_BAM_SORTED="{OUTDIR}/Bowtie2/{sample}_SL-{w}-{Q}_Min-{m}_bowtie2_{version}.sorted.bam"
    threads:
        16
    shell:
        """
        bowtie2 -x {BWT2_DB} -U {input} 2> {output.BWT2_ERR} > {output.BWT2_SAM}
        samtools view -bS -o {output.BWT2_BAM} {output.BWT2_SAM}
        samtools sort {output.BWT2_BAM} -o {output.BWT2_BAM_SORTED}
        samtools index {output.BWT2_BAM_SORTED}
        """


rule copy_to_pigz: # we just copy fastq files to gunzip them and use them in sortMeRNA, this way we don't touch the original ones
    input:
        DIR_FASTQ+"/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "{OUTDIR}/temp/{sample}.fastq.gz" # this temp directory will be deleted at the end of the pipeline in multiQC rule
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"


rule SortMeRNA:
    input:
        "OUTDIR/temp/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        fasta_pigz=temp("{OUTDIR}/temp/{sample}.fastq"),
        blast="{OUTDIR}/SortMeRNA/{sample}.fastq_SortMeRNA_{rRNAdb}.blast",
        log="{OUTDIR}/SortMeRNA/{sample}.fastq_SortMeRNA_{rRNAdb}.log"
    params:
        prefixSortMeRNA="{OUTDIR}/SortMeRNA/{sample}.fastq_SortMeRNA_{rRNAdb}",
        sortmerna_DB=config["SORTMERNA_DB"]
    shell:
        """
        pigz -d -k {input}
        sortmerna --ref {params.sortmerna_DB} --reads {output.fasta_pigz} --aligned {params.prefixSortMeRNA} --blast '1' --log TRUE
        """


rule multiQC:
    input: 
        expand(OUTDIR+"/FastQC/{sample}_fastqc.zip", sample=SAMPLES),
        expand(OUTDIR+"/Trimmomatic/{sample}_SL-"+str(w)+"-"+str(Q)+"_Min-"+str(m)+".fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES),
        expand(OUTDIR+"/Trimmomatic/{sample}_SL-"+str(w)+"-"+str(Q)+"_Min-"+str(m)+".stdout", sample=SAMPLES),
        expand(OUTDIR+"/Trimmomatic/{sample}_SL-"+str(w)+"-"+str(Q)+"_Min-"+str(m)+".stderr", sample=SAMPLES),
        expand(OUTDIR+"/Bowtie2/{sample}_SL-"+str(w)+"-"+str(Q)+"_Min-"+str(m)+"_bowtie2_"+version+".stderr", sample=SAMPLES),
        expand(OUTDIR+"/SortMeRNA/{sample}.fastq_SortMeRNA_"+rRNAdb+".blast", sample=SAMPLES),
        expand(OUTDIR+"/SortMeRNA/{sample}.fastq_SortMeRNA_"+rRNAdb+".log", sample=SAMPLES),
        tpl_plNGS=DIR_TPL+"/template-PL-NGS_multiqc_config.yaml",
        tpl_plBioinfo=DIR_TPL+"/template-PL-Bioinfo_multiqc_config.yaml"
    output:
        rap_plNGS="{OUTDIR}/multiQC/multiQC-PL09_{idNGS}.html",
        rap_plBioinfo="{OUTDIR}/multiQC/multiQC-PL21_{idNGS}.html"
    shell:
        """
        sed -e "s/ID_NGS_HERE/{idNGS}/g" < {input.tpl_plNGS} > {OUTDIR}/multiQC/PL-NGS_multiqc_config.yaml
        sed -e "s/ID_NGS_HERE/{idNGS}/g" < {input.tpl_plBioinfo} > {OUTDIR}/multiQC/PL-Bioinfo_multiqc_config.yaml
        multiqc -c {OUTDIR}/multiQC/PL-NGS_multiqc_config.yaml -n {output.rap_plNGS} {OUTDIR}/
        multiqc -c {OUTDIR}/multiQC/PL-Bioinfo_multiqc_config.yaml -n {output.rap_plBioinfo} {OUTDIR}/
        rm -r {OUTDIR}/temp
        """

onsuccess:
    shell("date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' > time_end_RNAseq.txt")
```

Is it because I use it in `params` and `output` in `SortMeRNA` rule and not in `inputs` of this rule ? Because for `version` in `Bowtie` rule, it doesn't seem to be problem to use it in `outputs` of the rule and not in `input`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `output` files need to have same wildcards, or else it would cause conflict in resolving job dependencies. Not all files in `output:` have `{rRNAdb}` wildcard, which is causing this problem. For example, if you have two `{rRNAdb}` values,  both would write to file `"{OUTDIR}/temp/{sample}.fastq"`, which snakemake correctly doesn't allow.

```py
rule SortMeRNA:
    input:
        "OUTDIR/temp/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        fasta_pigz=temp("{OUTDIR}/temp/{sample}.fastq"),
        blast="{OUTDIR}/SortMeRNA/{sample}.fastq_SortMeRNA_{rRNAdb}.blast",
        log="{OUTDIR}/SortMeRNA/{sample}.fastq_SortMeRNA_{rRNAdb}.log"
        """
```

PS - It appears you are mixing variable `OUTDIR` with wildcards, which will cause some other errors.